# What would be the best way to find an open space in a level?

Tags: xna, c#, tiles

I'm working on a 2D game where you use paint to add tiles to a level and right now I'm working to add warp tiles. I have it set up so certain direction-oriented paints use two points (a start and end) to determine which direction the tiles will point (left, right, up, down.) The warp tiles have these points, but they'll be added to two other lists (warp start and end). The way the warps work is: if the player hits one tile they'll be teleported to the corresponding warp tile. Now, if I'm going to get this to work properly, I need to make it so the player can't be teleported into a wall or off the map. So I need to move the point to an open tile exactly one space away from any walls.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you setting up these warp points beforehand or are they generated automatically somehow?

Comment: See my answer and description of the Packing Problem at
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/algorithm-to-fit-shapes-to-2d-grid

Comment: @Drackir The paint is just a particle trail that doesn't disappear or move and every particle has it's own point to map it's position. So I've made a for loop that checks each particles position, sees if that tile is open, changes the collision map accordingly and then removes the particle. The tile graphics are drawn according to the collision map.

Comment: I'm unbelievably confused. Perhaps an image would help people see what you're trying to do and give you solid answers.

Comment: @Drackir [Here's video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbhEFfIouQI) of the game thus far. Every time you lay down tiles, you change the values at that location on the collision map (an int array.) With the warp tiles I need 9 tiles worth of open space (all 9 tiles are equal to 0) and the warp tiles are created at the end points of the purple line (where the flags appear at 1:32.) What I need is a way to use a search algorithm to look around the old point for a new point that fits my guidelines (8 empty tiles around the new point which is also empty.) [Example.](http://i.imgur.com/LviLH.png)

Comment: Can players be teleported trought the walls?

Comment: Just simple "Off the map" and "in the wall" test ara trivial if You have some way to tell if position You test is "off the map" and "wall". Perhaps Your problem is more complex?

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is ensure that the clicked on tile has open tiles around it, I would just create a function that checks the tiles around it. And then call that on the clicked tile.

You could set it up in a (nested) loop or just create if statements for it. So, in pseudo-code:

```
function IsTileOpen(tile)
  if tile NOT open
    return false because if the clicked tile isn't open, why check any others
  if tile on top row
    return false because we're against the top wall
  if tile on left column
    return false because we're against the left wall
  if tile on right column
    return false because we're against the right wall
  if tile on bottom row
    return false because we're against the bottom wall
  if top left tile NOT open
    return false
  if top tile NOT open
    return false
  if top right tile NOT open
    return false
  if left tile NOT open
    return false
  if right tile NOT open
    return false
  if bottom left tile NOT open
    return false
  if bottom tile NOT open
    return false
  if bottom right tile NOT open
    return false
  return true because all the surrounding tiles were open
end function
```

**Edit Based On Comment**

There are two ways you could handle the situation:

1. (Easiest) You can just play a sound and indicate that the position they chose is invalid and they need to choose another option.
2. Use a search algorithm to find an open tile. However, I think there should be limits on how you use this. Take, for example, a situation where they click on the left side of the map and the only open spot is far on the right side. Your search algorithm finds that open spot and places the other warp there. This does not seem very intuitive and may be frustrating. My suggestion in this case (assuming you don't want to do #1 which is my main suggestion), is to only search the tiles around the current tile (perhaps in a n-tile radius). This way the warp gate won't appear too far from where you clicked. To do a search like this (assuming a 1-tile radius), you just need to call the function above on the eight tiles around the current one (assuming the current one wasn't available). You could do this in a loop or, again, with if statements.

Comment: I know how to do that, but I'm not sure how I can use a search algorithm to find a new point when the old point isn't open. I've been reading up on pathfinding and it seems like I could do something similar to that, where I would use Dijkstra's algorithm or A* algorithm to find the nearest open space. I'm just not sure how I could do that, because I've never programmed anything like it before. Sorry to be such a bother, I'm kind of new to programming, so I don't really know that much yet.

Comment: @IronGiraffe - Oh, I see what you mean. Ok, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @IronGiraffe - Updated.

Comment: Better do that "look if the tile is open" during level load or generation, and store the result. You usually have to pass through all tiles (at least, all loaded/visible tiles if you do lazy evaluation) at this point anyway, that little extra work doesn't matter, and the extra bits of memory shouldn't matter on most platforms either.

Comment: @Martin - From what I understand, the level changes as you play. See the video. And, I still recommend option 1 above, but if they have to do the second option, it's only on click so it's unlikely it will cause any *noticeable* hit to performance.

Comment: @Drackir: Unless the changes are to a big part of the level all at once or the status in question can potentially propagate through a bigger area ("visibility" or "connectedness" status can have such a property), updating this "open space" status locally the moment the level changes should incur no noticeable performance property.

Comment: @Martin - It has to be run at some point, it just depends when is best for this game. For example, if there's a lot of level editing going on, and we update the "open" status of the tiles around each edited tile, but only so that those values can be checked once or twice later on, it makes more sense to check it later on. On the other hand, if relatively small amounts of level editing occur, with lots of "open" checks later, it makes more sense to do it at the beginning. Either way, I think we can both agree that, if implemented properly, it won't negatively affect the game either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to find the nearest "free" rectangle to a warp tile, where the player can fit.

There is a similar question on stackoverflow. [Click to see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067883/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-find-a-non-colliding-rectangle-nearest-to-a-location).